# How can I pass a callback to a Libre office macro

Tags: callback, libreoffice-basic

Is it possible to pass a callback procedure to a Libre Office macro written in basic? For example, (a) to write a macro that applies processing specified by the caller to every cell in a range determined by the macro or (b)  to compare strings using a passed function to determine whether two characters should be considered equivalent.

Given that in my macros I can call Calc functions by their names with `com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess` and Uno functions with `com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper`, I thought I might be able to do something similar to call my own macros, and so pass in the name of the macro, but I have been unable to find anything about this. I also tried using `sheet.FunctionAccess` to call my own macros, but (perhaps unsurprisingly) could not get that to work.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [`.scriptProvider`](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/invoke-a-function-by-its-string-name/68608/3?u=johnsun)

Comment: @JohnSUN: Thanks, and sorry about the late reaction. It certainly looks like what I wanted, but I have not since had the need for it. I look forward to trying it when the need arises or I have time to experiment.